# How to sum across rows rows for specific columns in data table in R

Tags: r

I have a data table, see eg below:

```
A B C D 
1 a 2 4
2 b 3 5
3 c 4 6
```

with A,B,C,D as columns, I want to add a new column with sums across rows for column A,C and D. thus, new column should be

```
A B C D  SUM
1 a 2 4  7
2 b 3 5  9
3 c 4 6  13
```

Can someone please suggest.

Comment: `df$sum <- rowSums(df[, c('A', 'C', 'D')])`

Comment: thanks i was earlier using rowsum instead of rowSums hence was getting a error

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text ="A B C D

    1 a 2 4

    2 b 3 5

    3 c 4 6")

df %>% mutate(SUM = rowSums(select(df, c(A, C, D))))
```